# Disable DTLS retransmissions with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I want to run DTLS over a reliable transport. Is there a way to disable DTLS retransmissions in OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. In OpenSSL 1.1.1 (still in beta) you have the ability to specify a timer callback for defining a custom duration for the retransmit timer. If you specify a very long duration (such as UINT_MAX) then this will effectively disable retransmits. See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DTLS_set_timer_cb.html

If your reliable transport happens to be SCTP then you can use the built-in SCTP support which also disables the timer.